# Can I setup two NTFS disks as RAID-1 in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, raid, ntfs

I'm planning to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to replace Windows-7 on my desktop.

Currently, my PC has an SSD (for OS) and two HDDs configured as RAID-1 (mirrored, NTFS). I'll reformat SSD to install Ubuntu.

Is it possible, with Ubuntu, to setup existing NTFS HDDs as RAID-1 without reformatting or loosing the data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if your RAID controller is supported by Linux kernel.

For example, if you use your motherboard internal RAID feature (usually soft-RAID), then you are lucky. But, anyway, I recommend you to make a backup and reassemble your HDDs into RAID with a native Linux filesystem (EXT4, XFS etc.). If your RAID is currently assembled via soft-RAID feature of your motherboard, I suggest switch it to simple SATA or AHCI mode and assemble your soft-RAID via Linux tools like `mdadm` or `LVM`. Usually it gives better performance.

There's no practical need to use the "alien" NTFS filesystem on Linux.